# UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> to [NSObject : AnyObject]

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsevent, nsresponder

I am overriding NSResponder’s `mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent)` method and want to retrieve the value I set when creating a NSTrackingArea in Swift. I am using [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTrackingArea/initWithRect:options:owner:userInfo:) constructor to create the NSTrackingArea and pass the following object as `userInfo`.

```
let trackerData = ["myTrackerKey": view]
let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: trackingRect, options: [.EnabledDuringMouseDrag, .MouseEnteredAndExited, .ActiveInActiveApp], owner: self, userInfo: trackerData)
```

(`view : NSView` as well as `trackingRect : NSRect` do exist)

I am setting `trackerData` as `userInfo` so I can read it later in `mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent)`.

```
override func mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    // This does not work
    let data1 = theEvent.userData as [NSObject : AnyObject]
    let data2 = theEvent.userData as [String : NSView]
    let data3 = theEvent.userData as NSDictionary
}
```

My code is based on this [Objective-C Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CustomMenus/Listings/SuggestionsWindowController_m.html) provided by Apple. To quote line 372 of `SuggestionsWindowController.m`:

```
HighlightingView *view = [(NSDictionary*)[event userData] objectForKey: kTrackerKey];
```

So how can I read the event’s `userData`?

I have looked at [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492817/unsafemutablepointervoid-to-concrete-object-type) but it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read `trackerData` from the event, you have to get the user info from the tracking area

```
if let userInfo = theEvent.trackingArea?.userInfo {
  let trackerData = userInfo["myTrackerKey"]! as! NSView
  // do something with the view
}
```